# Problems with a bilingual joomla 3.2 site

Tags: joomla, menu, multilingual

I have a custom made Joomla 3.2 template and am now trying to make it bilingual. Let's start with the modules:

I have one language switcher module, set to position "language". This position is referenced in the xml file and in the index file using the jdoc:include statement.
I have two menu modules, one for each language, both are set to be on the same position.

Menu's:

I have one menu with one menu item that is set to default and the language is set to all. The menu item's access is set to public and it is not published.

The other two menu's I have are the English and German menu. The menu item's of both menu's are set to the corresponding language, linked to an article and associated with the corresponding menu item of the other language.

All I get on the front end is the English site, the language switcher module is showing, however, I can only ever see the British flag. The German one does not appear.

Trying to change the URL's ending from index.php/en/ to index.php/de/ does not work either.

Comment: did you add german as a content language (administrator-extensions-language manager-content?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I had a small mistake in the German language tag. What I had was "de - DE" what I should have had was: "de-DE". Without spaces.

Note that by changing the language tag in the language manager, all articles and menu items that you set to that particular language will disappear. Just make sure that after you change the language tag you also check your menu items and article. If you don't they will not show up on the front end.